# Matching values of column within dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Market         Price  date      outtime  intime  ttype
ATLJFKJFKATL   150    20190403  0215     0600    2
ATLJFK         77     20190403  0215     null    1
JFKATL         88     20190403  0600     null    1
JFKATL         77     20190403  0400     null    1
```

I'd like to take all ttypes (roundtrip = 2, one way = 1) that are roundtrip (2) and match it with the corresponding one ways and then add two columns with the price of each. How would I do this?

Result Dataframe:

```
Market         Price  date      outtime  intime  outbound  inbound
ATLJFKJFKATL   150    20190403  0215     0600    77        88
```

It could also look like this:

```
Market         Price  date      outtime  intime  inOutList
ATLJFKJFKATL   150    20190403  0215     0600    [77,88]
```

either way works.
Sometimes there won't be a one way to match, so the value will either be null or empty.

Comment: are there any keys to match on?

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala No keys to match, just checking to see if there are two one ways for the round trip. Finding one way for outbound roundtrip[:6] and finding inbound roundtrip[6:]

Answer (score 0):

You need to join roundtrip with single trips twice. Your joining keys is `Market`, `date` and `time`. Roundtrip markets have to be split into 6 character codes to match single trip markets:

First, let's split the dataframe into single trips and roundtrips:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf
single, roundtrip = [df.filter(psf.col('ttype') == i).drop('ttype') for i in [1, 2]]
```

To extract outbound and inbound markets for roundtrips, we simply use `substring`:

```py
roundtrip = roundtrip \
    .withColumn('outMarket', psf.substring('Market', 0, 6)) \
    .withColumn('inMarket', psf.substring('Market', 7, 6))
```

We can now join twice (for outbound and inbound):

```py
single = single \
    .drop('intime') \
    .withColumnRenamed('outtime', 'time') \
    .withColumnRenamed('Price', 'bound')
single.persist()

for bound in ['out', 'in']:
    roundtrip = roundtrip \
        .join(
            single.select([psf.col(c).alias(bound + c) for c in single.columns if c != 'date'] + ['date']), 
            on=[bound + c for c in ['Market', 'time']] + ['date'], how='left')

roundtrip.show()

        +--------+------+--------+---------+-------+------------+-----+--------+-------+
        |inMarket|intime|    date|outMarket|outtime|      Market|Price|outbound|inbound|
        +--------+------+--------+---------+-------+------------+-----+--------+-------+
        |  JFKATL|  0600|20190403|   ATLJFK|   0215|ATLJFKJFKATL|  150|      77|     88|
        +--------+------+--------+---------+-------+------------+-----+--------+-------+
```